# Microsoft CNTK Unsupported Windows Version 8.1

Tags: python, anaconda, cntk

> Anaconda version: 3 4.1.1
>
> Python version: 3 5.2
>
> Windows version: 8.1 x64

I've installed Python-only CNTK v2.6 succesfully via PyPI and tested with:

```
python -c "import cntk; print(cntk.__version__)"
```

After that there is an unsupported error:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py_init.py:32: UserWarning: Unsupported
Windows version (8.1). CNTK supports Windows 10 and above, only.
warnings.warn('Unsupported Windows version (%s). CNTK supports Windows 10 and above, only.' % __my_distro_ver__) 2.6
```

Is there any way to run CNTK on windows 8.1?

Comment: Microsoft does not want you to run outdated Windows versions that have reached the end of support.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the UserWarning. Either that or you [build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Setup-CNTK-with-script-on-Windows) from source.

To disable warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```